# Division by Power of 2 Explanation

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

**Background:**
I am interested in boolean logic and understanding how things work at a bit level. I am working through some problems I found online [here](http://fpl.cs.depaul.edu/jriely/373/lectures/class-02-004.html).

I'm specifically having trouble with dividing by some power of two. I tried walking through a solution, but I am still having trouble understanding what's going on.

```
    /* 
     * divpwr2 - Compute x/(2^n), for 0 <= n <= 30
     *  Round toward zero
     *   Examples: divpwr2(15,1) = 7, divpwr2(-33,4) = -2
     *   Legal ops: ! ~ & ^ | + << >>
     *   Max ops: 15
     *   Rating: 2
     */
    int divpwr2(int x, int n) {

        int xMSB = ((x>>31) & 1);
        int bias = xMSB;
        bias = bias << n;
        bias += ((xMSB<<31) >>31); 
        return ((x + bias) >> n);    
    }
```

**What I know/Problem:**
So from my understanding, if you need to multiply, you shift bits to the left. If you want to divide, you need to shift bits to the right. That would make me think that I would need to do something like:

```
x >> (2 << n)
```

However, it can't be that straight forward because of 2's complement. I need to determine if x is positive or negative. I can do that by finding the most significant bit. You can do that by shifting to the right by 31. Here is where I start having trouble:

15 >> 31 /// MSB = 0 
-33 >> 31 /// MSB =1

If I compute 0&1, that is 0. If I do 1&1, that is 1. 
**Question 1:** What is the point of using `& 1` here `((x>>31) & 1);`?

**Question 2:** Also, what is the point of multiplying the MSB by n here `bias = bias << n;`?
Why not just skip these two steps:

```
bias = bias << n;
bias += ((xMSB<<31) >>31);
```

My logic is, if I multiply the bias by n (`bias = bias << n;`), I get 0 if the MSB is 0. If the bias is 1, I just get n. So, I tried to remove the lines, and I still get the right answers for the given test parameters:

```
public int divpwr2(int x, int n) {

    int xMSB = ((x>>31) & 1);
    return ((x + xMSB) >> n);
}
```

But, I've looked at some other similar solutions, and I am wondering, is there something in the two lines that I need logic wise that I am overlooking?

This isn't homework. I'm just interested in learning more about boolean logic and how things work at a bit level. I know there are a few similar questions, I just didn't find anything that answered my questions.

Comment: `is there something in the two lines that I need logic wise that I am overlooking?` - doesn't look like it: the `bias` value is calculated but never referenced.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError That was a paste mistake. It is used in the return statement. I fixed the error.